# La columna 'precio' en field list es desconocida

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

estoy teniendo un problema al hacer un insert como este

```
INSERT INTO `prodped`(`id_producto`, `cantidad`, `id_pedido`) VALUES (20, 1, 1);
```

El tema es que en la tabla prodped no existe tal columna, si no que esa columna está en la tabla productos como muestro a continuacion:

```
drop table if EXISTS productos;
CREATE TABLE productos (
   id_producto tinyint primary key not null auto_increment,
   rutaImg varchar(50),
   nombre varchar(150),
   precio decimal(5, 2)
);
drop table if exists pedidos;
CREATE TABLE  pedidos  (
   id_pedido  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   fecha  date NOT NULL,
   id_cliente  int,
   precio_total smallint,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id_pedido ),
  KEY  id_cliente  ( id_cliente ),
  CONSTRAINT  pedidos_ibfk_1  FOREIGN KEY ( id_cliente ) REFERENCES  usuarios  ( id_usuario )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

drop table if exists prodPed;
create table prodPed(
   idProdPed int primary key auto_increment not null,
   id_producto tinyint,
   cantidad tinyint,
   id_pedido int,
   FOREIGN key (id_producto) REFERENCES productos(id_producto) on delete RESTRICT,
   FOREIGN key (id_pedido) REFERENCES pedidos(id_pedido) on DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Y no entiendo el por qué.

Agradecería una mano lo antes posible

Comment: Aquí tienes varias: ☚ ☛ ☜ ☝ ☞ ☟     .... Te recomiendo borrar la pregunta, ya que por un lado la resolviste, la consulta mostrada no tiene problema alguno y es imposible que tengas una mejor respuesta

Comment: Por cierto, phpmyadmin nada tiene que ver con la pregunta (es una herramienta de gestión, no la base de datos como tal), tampoco PHP (lenguaje de programación). Probablemente trabajás con MariaDB o MySQL. Pon solo etiquetas realmente relevantes para la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Ya está solucionado, el problema estaba en un trigger que afectaba a la tabla `prodPed` y era ahi donde estaba mal el precio